# Input take the class "btn-lg" automatically

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Input takes automatically the class 'btn-lg' after some seconds when the user add email address.

Initially:

```
<input class="submit btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="sendtest" value="Send test">
```

After 7 sec:

```
<input class="submit btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="sendtest" value="Send test">
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What to do in order to not allow the input takes this class?
I don`t want it.